# How to read json file correctly using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to create HTML selectors and to get their values from JSON, I created JSON and tried to read it simply by adding one more  in html document and then just parse into variable with JS, but it doesn't work, answers which I found didn't really help.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Select list</label>
        <select id = "Coutries">

        </select>
        <select id = "Bands">

        </select>
        <select id = "Albums">

        </select>   
    </form> 
    <script src="data.json"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
const data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load JSON through a `script` element. Instead, in your `script.js`, you can [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) it:

```
fetch("data.json")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // Use the data here, it's been parsed
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error here
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
$.getJSON('yourFile.json', function(data) {
    var arr= [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    var tempArr=[key,val]
        arr.push( tempArr );
      });
    });
```

Comment: There's no indication in the question of the user using jQuery. Neither is there any indication that they want to convert `data` into an array of arrays.